# Is there a log viewer for a vnext build log?

Tags: tfs-2015, logfile, azure-pipelines

When looking at a vnext build in TFS 2015, I often see this:

> The log is too big to be displayed in the browser. You can download
>   the build logs and view them offline.

E.g.
[image: TFS Build Log too big error]

When downloaded, these are just text files, and whilst notepad can open them you don't get the nice colouring you do if they're on screen which highlights warnings and errors.

Is there an application  that makes viewing these easier?

Comment: Does it happen when you view the entire log only? Is it possible to see individual steps logs?

Comment: @yan I believe tfs has a size limit that it will display (haven't quite worked out the kb size). Some individual are ok, others not

Comment: I got the same question but I cannot see where to download them, can you tell me where you downloaded them from?

Comment: @CreeTar added an image

Comment: Ah ok, I use Notepad++ and created my own style to highlight them (http://imgur.com/ifu3htC). But for another log file I used the Notepad++ `Python Script` plugin, parsing an xml file and generating a tabbed CSV for excel from it that uses highlighting and folding, but you could also generate a html using `editor.getText().split("\n")` then work on it storing stuff in a variable and after you create a new notepad++ tab with your content using `notepad.new()` and simply `print myContentVar`

Comment: I'm assuming that the bulk of the output is from the Powershell script. One work-around would be to break-up the steps into smaller steps and include multiple Powershell script steps (each with less output), and then click on the individual step to filter just on that step.

Answer (score 0):

There's no parser explicity for this purpose (TFS vNext Log file parsing).

There are, however, many Log Parser tools available that can do this. The following post is an (opinion-based) list of log parsers that might be useful:

- [What is the best log analysis tool that you used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154982/what-is-the-best-log-analysis-tool-that-you-used)

TFS build logs are space-delimited, and hierarchically organized, so this may have an impact on which tools are up to the job. Rules can probably be put in place to format/colour based on tokens such as `##[debug]` or `##[warning]`, though.

Many people seem to like [Log Parser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) (command-line based) along with the [GUI](http://www.lizard-labs.com/log_parser_lizard.aspx) that goes on top of it, given that it supports querying.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33433490/3063884