# How to increase the log file size threshold for TFS 2015 Build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

So those of us using the new TFS build system will undoubtedly have come across this rather annoying message:

[image: Tfs build log]

Has anyone came across a setting for this and how to eliminate or increase it? In this particular example, my log file is just over 2MB. Of course I can download the logs but I'm happy to wait a few seconds for this to load! I want the errors and warnings highlighted and coloured nicely in my scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately,there are no such settings.

You can use some useful tools to help you analyze your log. Such as [Log Parser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659)  , [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) ... More for your choice :[What is the best log analysis tool that you used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154982/what-is-the-best-log-analysis-tool-that-you-used)